# Как поменять ascii-код переменной?

Tags: c++

Хочу поменять ascii-код переменной `а`, но получаю ошибку:

> prog.cpp:13:12: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a;
    cin >> a;
    int h = (int) a;;
    for (int g = 65; g <= 90; g++){
        if ((int) a == g){
            h = h + 32;
            (int) a = h;
            cout << a;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы приводите `a` к *значению* типа `int`, а присваивать можно только переменной. Вы же не напишете `2 = 3+5;` :)

Я бы мог показать, как реально это сделать, но это опасная игра - тогда в `char` вы сможете записать то, что там не поместится, а это не нужно...

Так что не надо этих игр, и просто напишите `a = h;` - ведь `char` - это просто такой однобайтный `int` (ну, или беззнаковый - в зависимости от компилятора и его настроек).

Вобщем, относитесь к `char` как к целочисленному значению. Как символ он проявляет себя только при вводе-выводе...

Comment: А как реально это сделать? Я только через указатели представляю, но это некрасиво как-то .

Comment: @pavel А только и получится - через указатели и ссылки: `*(int*)&a = 1000; (int&)a = 1000;`. Я имел в виду именно это. Но это же крайне нездоровое занятие, компилятор возмущен :)

Answer (score 1):

Понятие ascii-код переменной попросту не существует.

Если вы говорите о символе - то это само его внутреннее содержание, если рассматривать его не как символ, который он представляет, а как значение, которое он содержит.